# python import root folder and use all subfolders

Tags: python, import

With the following dir structure

```
.
├── setup.py
└── yourpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── some_module.py
    ├── other_module.py
    └── sub_package
        ├── __init__.py
        └── more_modules.py
```

Is it possible to do this:

```
>> import yourpackage as yp
>> yp.some_module.bar()
>> yp.sub_package.more_modules.foo()
```

where the contents of `some_module` is

```
def bar(): print('bar')
```

where the contents of `more_modules` is

```
def foo(): print('foo')
```

I can't seem to get this to work

EDIT: The error I would get in the first case is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'yourpackage' has no attribute 'some_module'
```

In the second case, it's a similar error, but with `more_modules`

Comment: From which file are you running the code?

Comment: From the python interpreter at the root. I do a `pip install -e .` first

Comment: Please mention the error you are getting in the question

Comment: added error message

Comment: does your `__init__.py` file contain an import for `some_module` ?

Comment: No it didn't, but if it does, it yields the error `ImportError: No module named 'some_module'`

Comment: is there a reason why you don't just do something like `from yourpackage.some_module import bar` - this assumes the file is at the same directory as `yourpackage` ?

Comment: No reason. I just wanted my package to be more like "pandas". In pandas I would just do `import pandas as pd` and then use stuff like `pd.DataFrame` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pile on the answer of @A.Joly and @slallum: actually, I found a combination of their methods actually works. I created these:

```
pycharmprojects
   |_networkxy
       |_ main_run.py  ---- misleading name, it's just an ordinary file
       |_ more_module.py
       |_ __init__.py
```

content of `__init__.py`:

```
from . import main_run
from . import more_module
```

content of `main_run.py`:

```
def some_module():
    print('some module')
```

content of `more_module.py`:

```
def more_module():
    print('more module')
```

Now, at directory `pycharmprojects`, in command line:

```
(C:\Users\Name\.conda\envs\my_root) C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import networkxy
>>> networkxy.main_run.some_module()
some module
>>> networkxy.more_module.more_module()
more module
```

Note: for some reasons, I cannot do `import main_run` in `__init__.py`, but the `from . import *` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! All this time, what I was missing was `from . import some_module`. Btw `from . import *` didnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the inner modules without importing them explicitly you have to import them in the `__init__.py` file:

```
import some_module
import other_module
import sub_package
```

and in `sub_package/__init__.py`:

```
import more_modules
```

Note that that might make the first import of the module slower.

**Other option** is to import them explicitly in your code:

```
>> import yourpackage.some_module
>> import yourpackage.sub_package.more_modules
>> yourpackage.some_module.bar()
>> yourpackage.sub_package.more_modules.foo()
```

Comment: when I use `import some_module` in `__init__.py`, I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'some_module'`

Answer (score 0):

Imports are quite tricky in fact ...

you could do as follows:

```
import yourpackage as yp
from yourpackage import some_module  #yp does not work
```

call in ipython:

```
In [8]: yp.some_module.bar()
bar
```

then

```
import yourpackage.sub_package
from yourpackage.sub_package import more_modules
```

call in ipython:

```
In [20]: yp.sub_package.more_modules.foo()
foo
```

You have to import top package then subpackages ...

Here's an interesting link: https://www.codementor.io/sheena/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1

and this one as well :) : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: so it doesn't work without explicitly calling `from yourpackage import some_module` ?

Comment: yes, unless you do : from yourpackage import *, which is the worst thing to do. Though I haven't tried it here, I'm not sure it works with subpackages.